# How to extend 3d surface graph

Tags: 3d, plotly, surface, plotly.js

i am new in plotly. I have 3d surface graph in plotly.js, but data on y axis are densely stored and i want to extend space between data on y axis. 
I try use axis range and some other parameters but nothing works good. 
Thanks
[image: 3dsurface]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be able to experiment and increase the aspect ratio for Y by adding the below code (see the plotly guide for the exact placement) the scene goes inside the layout:

https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-axes/

```
scene: {
    aspectmode: "manual",
    aspectratio: {
        x: 1, y: 7, z: 1,
    },
}
```